# Trying to open a series of netCDF files with using OpenDAP

Tags: dask, netcdf, python-xarray, noaa

I want to open all the data from 1950-2005 using xarray and open_mfdataset.
https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/catalog/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/surface/catalog.html

This is what I have done so far:

source=https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/catalog/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/surface/air.sig995.years.nc

```
    files = [source for years in range(1950,2005,1)]
    ds=xr.open_mfdataset(files)
    print(ds)
```

However, I cannot seem to get my list interpreted to be read into the variable years within source.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
    `path = 'https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/catalog/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/surface'
files = ['{0}/air.sig995.{1:04d}.nc'.format(path, years) for years in range(1950,2005,1)]
print(files) 
nc = netCDF4.MFDataset(files)`

This is the code I am using.  When I try to open up these files I get an error:

```
OSError: [Errno -90] NetCDF: file not found: b'https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/thredds/catalog/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis/surface/air.sig995.1948.nc'
```

Did I not enter the path correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files are named `air.sig995.YYYY.nc`, so you need something like:

```
files = ['air.sig995.{0:04d}.nc'.format(years) for years in range(1950,2005,1)]
```

Which produces:

```
In [2]: files
Out[2]: 
['air.sig995.1950.nc',
 'air.sig995.1951.nc',
 'air.sig995.1952.nc',
 'air.sig995.1953.nc',
 .....
```

You can also easily include a (remote) path here (if required):

```
path = '/some/file/path'
files = ['{0}/air.sig995.{1:04d}.nc'.format(path, years) for years in range(1950,2005,1)]
```

See https://pyformat.info/ for more information on string formatting in Python.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I was unsure how to reference the dates as a variable within the remote path.  What would be the best way to combine these into one continuous time series?  Maybe xarray?

Comment: Exactly xarray. You could use `xr.auto_combine`.